# The MediaStreamTrack.stop() method stops the track is not working. Still camera is on

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webrtc, video-streaming, simple-peer

I created a video calling system. But when I disconnect the call the camera should off. I used  `MediaStreamTrack.stop()` to stop all tracks but it's not working.

**Code to stop the stream:-**

```
  const tracks = stream.getTracks();
  tracks.forEach((track) => {
    track.stop();
  });
  stream.load();
  remoteStream.current.srcObject = null;
  localSteam.current.srcObject = null;
```

After stopping the stream still getting this....
[image]

Comment: you need to stop all tracks for *every* stream you acquired via getUserMedia. Most likely you have a dangling track somewhere.